# How do I implement Dependency Injection when many new objects instances are required?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying understand some DI concepts. One could easily convert a single instance per dependency as in this example.

**Non DI**

```
$my_cal = new MyCal();

class MyCal {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->date  = new MyDate();
        $this->label = new MyLabel();
    }
}
```

**DI**

```
$my_date  = new MyDate();
$my_label = new MyLabel();
$my_cal   = new MyCal($my_date, $my_label);

class MyCal {
    public function __construct(MyDate $date_class, MyLabel $label_class) {
        $this->date  = $date_class;
        $this->label = $label_class;
    }
}
```

But how could  a class with many instance calls (say 30, for example) be converted?

**Non DI**

```
$my_cal = new MyCal();

class MyCal {
    public function __construct() {
        $today       = new MyDate(...);
        $tomorrow    = new MyDate(...);
        $next_day    = new MyDate(...);
        $yesterday   = new MyDate(...);
        $another_day = new MyDate(...);
        // ...
        $label1 = new MyLabel(...);
        $label2 = new MyLabel(...);
        $label3 = new MyLabel(...);
        $label4 = new MyLabel(...);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Could this possibly be when a container or factory would be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.
You only need to pass ONCE the dependency. In this case you should do something like this:

```
$date = new MyDate();

class MyCal {
   function __construct( MyDate $dateService ) {
        $today       = $dateService->get('today');
        $tomorrow    = $dateService->get('tomorrow');
        $next_day    = $dateService->get('next_day');
        ...
   }
}
```

By this you are exposing the fact that your class depends on another object of `MyDate` and you simply pass it once.

Comment: This gives me only one instance of the passed in class. In my example I am using several.

Comment: did you see those `->get` method? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly the MyDate class "get" method handles date creation instead of a distinct date factory class? I wonder if `$today = $dateService->get('04/08/2013');` makes more sense in your example. Essentially yes to using a factory then?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused because your example doesn't use a separate factory class like the wiki you linked. I'm trying to implement a clean code approach like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0 if that helps explain what I'm doing.